# Can assertEquals(Long,Integer) succeed?

Tags: java, junit

Currently I am doing some code review and I found this line of code which interrupts the testcase:

```
assertEquals(Long.valueOf(4321), lMessage.getNumber());
```

`getNumber` returns an `Integer` which is also `4321`.
I changed it to this:

```
assertTrue(4321 == lSavedStoerung.getMessage());
```

because in my understanding of the equals method the `assertEquals` can never return true in the first example. With my `assertTrue` all test cases running fine.

Or did I understand something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that having method return an `Integer` instead of a `Long` is not a mistake?

Comment: getNumber returns Integer. I am absolutly sure about that.

Comment: assertEquals() is generally better than assertTrue() because when your test fails, the output will contain both the expected and actual value.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The reason why `assertEquals` test has failed is that equality considers not only the value of the number, but also its type. `java.lang.Long` object does not compare as `equal` to a `java.lang.Integer`.

Since `lMessage.getNumber()` returns an `int`, Java wraps it into `Integer` before passing to `assertEquals`. That's why you could fix the test case by using `Integer.valueOf` instead:

```
assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(4321), lMessage.getNumber());
```

Comment: would it be bad if I use assertTrue? Becouse at that place I am only interested in the value.

Comment: Or more simply: `assertEquals(4321, lMessage.getNumber());`.

Comment: @StefanBeike Using `assertTrue` is not bad, you can use it if it serves your purpose.

Comment: @assylias then I get the compiler error: "The method assertEquals(Object, Object) is ambiguous for the type MessageDaoTest."

Answer (score 1):

What is the reason behind 4321 being a long? If it's not necessary use the integer solution dasblinkenlight sugested.

```
assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(4321), lMessage.getNumber());
```

or

```
assertEquals(4321, lMessage.getNumber());
```

On the other hand, if your code allows `lMessage.getNumber()` return a long depending on the circumstances then you could box it into a long for your test.

```
assertEquals(Long.valueOf(4321), (long) lMessage.getNumber());
```

PS: Getting too compfortable using assertTrue & == will cause you trouble if you ever compare something that does not come in a primitive data type, but it will not in this specific example.